# How can we query the already create " LogGroup" and "StreamName" in cloudwatch with AWS SDK C++?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am working on a project on which I need to query the "Log Group" and "Log Stream" to know that it is already present there or not using the language c++.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During working on that I have found the answer for that is:

when we create the  "**Log Group"** and "**Log Stream**" using AWS SDK then at that time in the response we get error message with all the details and reason to not to created the  "Log Group" and "Log Stream".

So from the Error message we are able to get the message **"ALREADY EXISTED"**.

So based on that message we can identified that particular group or stream is already existed or not.